# When does the shape operator commutes with a differential?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, surfaces, curvature, tangent-bundle

Suppose we have a smooth map $\varphi : S\to H$ between two regular parametric surfaces in $\mathbb{R}^3.$ Then at any point $p\in S,$ we have following maps between corresponding tangent spaces:
$\require{AMScd}$\begin{CD}
T_pS @>d\varphi_p>> T_{\varphi(p)}H\\
@V dn_{S, p} V V @VV dn_{H, \varphi(p)} V\\
T_pS @>>d\varphi_p> T_{\varphi(p)}H
\end{CD}

where $dn_{S, p}: T_pS\to T_pS$ is the shape operator (differential of the Gauss map). Now, I wonder about the necessary and sufficient conditions that make this diagram commutative. I have no idea, to begin with. Also, if any, what are the interesting geometric implications when these two linear maps commute?

Comment: I suggest you start with the more basic question: Given $T\colon V\to W$ and self-adjoint linear maps $S\colon V\to V$ and $\bar S\colon W\to W$, when do we have $\bar S\circ T = T\circ S$? Focus, perhaps, on eigenvectors, and then on when self-adjointness is preserved.